# Where is Finder Sync Extension template

Tags: xcode

I would like to create a Creating a Finder Sync Extension in Xcode:
See this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

But the template is no where in Xcode, do you know where.

Also this talks about a template:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your existing macOS project, select the project and then click the plus at the bottom of the targets list, or choose **File / New / Target...**

You're then presented with the template chooser, the Finder Sync extension is in the Application Extension group:

[image]